# Any way to fix "command timed out" GDB error for an SFML-using program in CLion?

Tags: c++, sfml, clion

The problem is that GDB fails to get debug info from some places of a program using SFML. CLion specs:

- CLion 2016.1.3
- MinGW-w64 3.4
- GDB 7.8.1

I found an answer suggesting to stop anti-virus software for a while, but it did not work.

Code sample:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "myproject");

    Interface interface (window);
    /* Setting up 'interface'*/

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            /* Capture events */
        }
        window.clear ();
        interface.draw (); // Breakpoint here, information captured instantly
    }
}
```

Going inside interface.draw():

```
void draw () {
    for (FramePtr &ptr : activeFrameStack) // Debugger fails to get info here
        ptr->draw (window);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the recently released 2016.2 version with 'command timeout' problem fixed and bundled GDB updated to 7.11 (https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/07/clion-2016-2-released/).

Comment: @Corne Please repost the debug logs as described here to our support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206560589-What-to-do-if-debugger-doesn-t-work-as-expected-